# What to keep for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I have submitted an iPhone app to Apple for approval and distribution.

What do I need to save of the code and compilations to be able to bug-fix if (when?) the bugs come in? Should I just save everything, or just the symbols file?

Comment: Why would you like to not save the hole project? I always save everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the all the source code and the resources needed to build the app into a source code repository (with an appropriate tag) as soon as I submit an app build.  In addition I zip and backup the .dSYM directory in my build/Distribution-iphoneos directory, just in case something changes in my tool environment.

Having an exact source snapshot allows me to do things such as insert NSLog statements, etc., while trying to replicate the problem, if that helps narrow down a problem source (and then reverting if not), instead of just looking at (symbolicated) crash dumps.

Answer (score 3):

to decipher possible crash reports with symbolicatecrash tool you'll need to store symbols file.

Whether or not store other things is up to you I think, it may depend on what application updates do you plan to make. For example you may be still developing some new features and release an update with just hot bug fixes - in that case you need a separate branch in your source control for that. If you plan to ship an update that does not differ from your dev version separate branches may be not necessary.

But I personally make separate tag in svn with actual code used for each appstore submission - may be it is not always useful, but it certainly won't hurt.